# Scala by Example: spawn function in scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala

I'm trying implement section 17.9 Workers in Scala by Example book with Scala version 2.11.7.
Import statements:

```
import scala.concurrent._, scala.concurrent.ops._
```

was error "ops not is member of scala.concurrent". I did google and known that concurrent.ops is deprecated and rather by future, change import statement to:

```
import scala.concurrent._, scala.concurrent.Future._
```

Entire class source:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.Future._

class ComputeServer(n: Int) {

  private abstract class Job {
    type T
    def task: T
    def res(x: T)
  }

  private val openJobs = new Channel[Job]()

  private def processor(i: Int) {
    while(true) {
      val job = openJobs.read
      job.res(job.task)
    }
  }

  def future[A](p: => A): () => A = {
    val reply = new SyncVar[A]()
    openJobs.write{
      new Job{
        type T = A
        def task = p
        def res(x: A) = reply.put(x)
      }
    }
    () => reply.get
  }

  spawn(replicate(0, n){processor})
}
```

But occurs errors in line: `spawn(replicate(0, n){processor})`

```
not found: value spawn
not found: value replicate
missing arguments for method processor in class ComputeServer; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

What're spawn, replicate, processor function in version 2.11.7?

Comment: Spawn was used to create a thread with the code given inside. You can use Future { .... // code } for that. I don't know about replicate but you can find sources here http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_7_2_final/src/library/scala/concurrent/ops.scala?view=markup this api here is really old

Comment: I found replicate function belong to ops object in your url.

Comment: of course you found it, this is why I gave you the url... but it is outdated source

Answer (score 1):

one can create method spawn like this:

```
def spawn(p: => Unit) {
   val t = new Thread() { override def run() = p }
   t.start()
}
```